# Socket Send And Receive Buffer

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I tried to learn about the conception of Socket-Send(Receive)-Buffer.And I wrote these codes:
Client:

```
int client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int s = getsockopt(client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sendBuffSize, &len);
int status = connect(client, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
printf("The send buff size is : %d.\n", sendBuffSize);
char buf[100000];
int n, wn;
int fd = open("./1.txt", O_RDONLY);
while ((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
    wn = write(client, buf, n);
    printf("Write %d bytes.\n", wn);
}
```

Server: I set the connected client as **Non-block**,and add this client into the epoll.Once the client sends data to the server, I put the main thread into sleep[ten seconds].

```
char buf[8192];
sleep(10);
int rn;
while ((rn = read(events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
    printf("Read %d bytes.\n", rn);
}
```

The client send Buffer size is 16384 and the server receive Buffer size is 20000[setsockopt].

According to the book:The client calls the write function will block if the socket send buffer is full.

But I get the result[Client] :
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxTgU.png)

And the server :
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6cec.png)

Questions:

1. Receive buffer size + Send buffer size < 100000; but why the write function do not block?
2. Why the server read 8192 + 6808 = 15000 bytes instead of read continuously 8192 bytes?

Comment: Is this a curiosity thing or are you trying to design a program that actually relies on the size of the buffers?

Comment: Thank you for response.I am a beginner. I just want to understand the conception of socket buffer, so I wrote this program to checkout whether I really understand it.But the result makes me confused.

Comment: I think Linux includes some overhead per packet in the socket buffer size. For most programming you need to know *that* there's a socket buffer, but the exact size etc. is unreliable.

Comment: Thank you,I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no evidence here that the client writes did not block. On the contrary, the fact that all the writes were 100,000 bytes except the last, when you ran out of input, shows that it *must* have blocked, to transfer all that data into a socket buffer that is smaller.
2. TCP segmentizes, and IP packetises, the data sent over the wire. You have no control over that process. In any case a `read()` can transfer any amount of bytes from 1 up to the count supplied, or zero upwards in non-blocking mode. It is a streaming protocol, not a messaging protocol. There is no other guarantee about how much any individual `read()` will return at a time.

Comment: Thank you for response, I am just curious about the conception of socket buffer, and want to simulate the process on the book.But the result is not the same as book.

Comment: What result is not the same as what book? and why should it be? unless you are running exactly the same hardward and software?

Comment: The book is Unix Network Programming(Volume1,3rd),Section 2.11.I have no idea why and how it should be.I do not have the same hardware or software, if I cannot get the right phenomenon,all I can do is keep this conception in mind.Thanks.

Comment: The point is that there *isn't* a reason why it should be the same. Every hardware, every operating system, indeed every *connection* can behave differently, subject only to the defined semantics of the operations, which do not include exactly reproducing results from 25-year-old textbooks, good as this one undoubtedly is.